# Open new tab only for specific button?

Tags: jsf, facelets

How can I open a new tab on buttonclick only for a specific button?

This will open new tab for both, but I only want to have it for "Login".
Further, these buttons should still align side by side.

```
<h:form target="_blank">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:commandButton value="Login" />
        <h:commandButton value="Logout" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Is this ever possible?

Answer (score 2):

Set your form target into `_blank` with `onclick`

Like this :

```
<h:commandButton value="Login" onclick="this.form.target='_blank'"/>
```

Comment: This is not incorrect. But after clicking the `Login` button once, the `target` attribute of the form is permanently changed to `target="_blank"`. It means if you clicked the `Logout` button after clicking the `Login` button, again a new tab is opened. To prevent this you need to change the `Logout` button as below too. `<h:commandButton value="Logout" onclick="this.form.target='_self';"/>`